# Subclass a class that has Pointers to other classes

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I want to subclass a Class in Parse that has Pointers to other classes.

Here is my class:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using Parse; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[ParseClassName("UserCars")] public class UserCars : ParseObject {

[ParseFieldName("car")]
public Car car
{
    get { return GetProperty<Car>("car"); }
    set { SetProperty<Car>(value, "car"); }
}

[ParseFieldName("isBumpers")]
public bool isBumpers
{
    get { return GetProperty<bool>("isBumpers"); }
    set { SetProperty<bool>(value, "isBumpers"); }
}
```

When I execute this query below `isBumpers` returns an accurate bool value, but `car` is always null:

```
var query = new ParseQuery<UserCars>();

    query.WhereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.CurrentUser);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                                   {
        IEnumerable<UserCars> userCars = t.Result;

        foreach (UserCars u in userCars)
        {
            Debug.Log(u.car);
        }
});
```

I tried adding this with no change:

```
IEnumerable<UserCars> userCars = t.Result;

foreach (UserCars u in userCars)
{
    Task<Car> fCar = u.car.FetchIfNeededAsync();
    Debug.Log(u.car); 
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fCar is a Task, so basicly you should wait for it to complete.

Try writing this instead:

```cs
foreach (UserCars u in userCars )
{
    u.car.FetchIfNeededAsync().ContinueWith(result =>
    {
        Debug.Log(u.car);
    };
}
```

This will make sure you wait for the data to be correctly fetched.